# transforming request header using unbase64 and environment variables not working

Tags: http-headers, apache2

I am having trouble to base64 decode a request header with Apache.

The use case:

Incoming request has a Basic Authentication header:

```
"Authorization: Basic user:api_key"
```

Where 'user:api_key' is base64 encoded.

I need to transform the header into the below, before the requests gets passed on to the backend server (using mod_proxy_http):

```
"Authorization: Bearer api_key"
```

Where 'api_key' is not base64 encoded.

Most of the steps can be completed using 'Header edit' and some SetEnvIf with regex matches and usage of matching groups.

What I haven't been able to achieve is to decode the basic authentication string and use it in a / the header.

I have tried:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "Basic\ (.*)" "AUTH64=$1"
Header set my_header %{AUTH64}e
```

This works fine, but does not decode. (Just using my_header response header to easily debug using curl)

Trying to decode:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "Basic\ (.*)" "AUTH64=$1"
Header set my_header %{unbase64:%{AUTH64}e}

SetEnvIf Authorization "Basic\ (.*)" "AUTH64=$1"
Header set my_header %{unbase64:env:AUTH64}

SetEnvIf Authorization "Basic\ (.*)" "AUTH64=$1"
Header set my_header %{unbase64:%{AUTH64}}

SetEnvIf Authorization "Basic\ (.*)" "AUTH64=%{unbase64:$1}"
Header set my_header %{AUTH64}e

SetEnvIf Authorization "Basic\ (.*)" "AUTH64=%{unbase64($1)}"
Header set my_header %{AUTH64}e

SetEnvIf Authorization "Basic\ (.*)" "AUTH64=$1"
Header set my_header "expr=%{unbase64:%{AUTH64}e}"

SetEnvIf Authorization "Basic\ (.*)" "AUTH64=$1"
Header set my_header "expr=%{unbase64:env:AUTH64}"

SetEnvIf Authorization "Basic\ (.*)" "AUTH64=$1"
Header set my_header "expr=%{unbase64:%{AUTH64}}"
```

These all fail to decode either with an error, or the value in the header is something like

```
"my_header: unbase64:dXNlcjpwYXNz"
```

What does work is:

```
Header set my_header "expr=%{unbase64:dXNlcjpwYXNz}"
```

So the only step missing is on using the value from an environment variable instead of the literal base64 encoded value I have hardcoded in the last example above.

I also tried some options with rewrite rules, but I am running into the same problem that the unbase64 is not evaluated.

working:

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^Basic\ (.*)
   RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [E=AUTH64:%1]
```

not working:

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^Basic\ (.*)
   RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [E=AUTH64:unbase64(%1)]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^Basic\ (.*)
   RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [E=AUTH64:%{unbase64:%1}]
```

When I google I hardly find any example of using unbase64. The only working example is someone using an external program with rewrite rules, but that seems a bit over the top.

Is my usecase possible with Apache?

Thanks,

Valentijn

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have having is combining 2 module's in you apache configuration.
I can be possible that the env module has a later execution then the header module.

On the apache wiki there is a example with the same kind of purpose that you trying to do: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/LogBasicauthenticationusername

Working example that output the header in the application & set the output in response header:

```
# Set the Auth header to custom one.
RequestHeader set X-AUTH-DECODE "expr=%{HTTP:Authorization}"

# Grab the base 64 part
RequestHeader edit X-AUTH-DECODE "^Basic (.*)$" $1

# decode it
RequestHeader set X-AUTH-DECODE "expr=%{unbase64:%{HTTP:X-AUTH-DECODE}}"

# split on :
RequestHeader edit X-AUTH-DECODE "(.*):.*$" $1

# Set response header
Header onsuccess set X-AUTH-DECODE "expr=%{HTTP:X-AUTH-DECODE}"
```

Greet,
Egbert